# Laravel 'TypeGroup Class' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to get the `type_group` **name** to be displayed in the view, rather than the **id**.

I've tried *two* different ways below, but neither work, and I can't see what I'm missing?

**members table**

```
| uurn | member_name | type_group_id | is_expired | expired_on |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|      |             |               |            |            |
```

**type_group table**

```
| id | name |
_____________
|    |      |
```

I've got a `members` table, and a `type_group` table (as seen above)

I'm returning a view, and it works fine when I pull through the `type_group_id`, but it won't pull through the corresponding name, eg I'm trying to something along the lines of `type_group_id->name`

I've created models for both:

**Member.php Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Member extends Model {

    public function typeGroup() {
      retuurn $this->belongsTo('TypeGroup', 'type_group_id');
    }
  ...
```

**TypeGroup.php Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TypeGroup extends Model {

  protected $table = 'type_groups';

  public function members() {
    return $this->hasMany('Member');
  }
}
```

I've got the following for my controller:

**MembersController@Expired**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

use Carbon\Carbon;

use App\Member;
use App\Imported;
use App\TypeGroup;

...

public function dbMembers() {
$dbMembers = Member::all();
return view('expired')
  ->with("dbMembers", $dbMembers)
;
```

}

And the following is my view, and works, but returns the `id`.

**expired.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($dbMembers as $dbMember)
  <li>{{ $dbMember->uurn }} - {{ $dbMember->member_name }} ({{ $dbMember->type_group_id}}) </li>
@endforeach
```

Neither of the following work, and I can't see why?!

**expired.blade.php - v1**

```
@foreach ($dbMembers as $dbMember)
  <li>{{ $dbMember->uurn }} - {{ $dbMember->member_name }} ({{ $dbMember->type_group_id->name}}) </li>
@endforeach
```

**expired.blade.php - v2**

```
@foreach ($dbMembers as $dbMember)
  <li>{{ $dbMember->uurn }} - {{ $dbMember->member_name }} ({{ $dbMember->typeGroup->name}}) </li>
@endforeach
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

(Note, I've rejigged the code a bit to make the names more readable, but there may be a spelling mistake or name wrong. I don't think that's it, as it's returning the `id` as mentioned.

Comment: there is a error public function members() {
    retuurn $this->hasMany('Member');
  } change retuurn to return

Comment: Thanks. As below, I think that's where I deleted some other code and comments that weren't relevant. Making the change still has an issue.

Comment: instead of returning the view can you just return dbmembers; and let me know the output

Comment: change this this public function typeGroup() {
      retuurn $this->belongsTo('TypeGroup', 'type_group_id');
    }  to public function typeGroup() {
      return $this->belongsTo(TypeGroup::class, 'type_group_id');
    }
adn do same for members model

Comment: Made the change above (appending `::class` in the model, and it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: have you changed it in both models?

Comment: make you sure you appended ::class with out '' Member::class is correct not 'Member::class'

Comment: Sorry, missed that! The error message has now changed to 'Trying to get property 'name' of non-object'

Comment: okay now try this $dbMember->typeGroup->name

Comment: As above... Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: have you tried both ways?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176570/discussion-between-salman-zafar-and-n8udd).

Answer (score 0):

you do seem to have a typo in the word `return` here:

```
class Member extends Model {

    public function typeGroup() {
      retuurn $this->belongsTo('TypeGroup', 'type_group_id');
      // ^^^^
    }
}

class TypeGroup extends Model {

  protected $table = 'type_groups';

  public function members() {
    retuurn $this->hasMany('Member');
    // ^^^^
  }
}
```

Fix that, let us know if it helped

Comment: Thanks. I think that's where I deleted some other code and comments that weren't relevant. Making the change still has an issue.